# Best way to give notice to boss if I haven't signed the contract but boss is going on holidays imminently

Tags: notice-period, resignation

I have received a verbal offer from another company this morning and I have accepted it.
The company has just now requested my postal address from the recruiter. (I assume this is to send me the written contract).

The problem is my boss is going on holidays for 2 and half weeks end of today. I have a very good relationship with him and I greatly value the mentorship he has given me.

I believe I have 3 options:

1. Verbally face-to-face inform him today
2. Call him next week once I have signed the contract
3. Verbally face-to-face inform him on his return

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would sign the contract before anything else  as when you sign its legally binding so should anything go wrong they cant retract the offer, then tell him how ever you can,

I have actually had this same issue before, this is what I did:

- I waited for the official offer to come through, agreed and signed the paper work
- I then emailed HR so it was official (that was our company policy).
- Then I asked HR not to inform my boss but start proceedings as I wanted to tell him out of respect, as my boss was on holiday and couldnt wait I then called him, apologised it happened this way and told him I had no other choice as it was time sensitive.
- I then told the rest of the team and people I wanted to know the following day, once i had replies from HR and my boss.

So with you I would say:

- Wait for the official offer to come through, agree and signed the paper work to make it official first. Before you don't have any obligation to until its official. This also protects you incase something happens and you will be protected.
- Tell HR.
- Tell him face to face, if not call him and explain you are sorry you are having to do it this way but you have no other choice.

Answer (score 7):

Wait.

You haven't signed anything yet. The verbal offer may have not told you about some very important detail that you will never accept. That could mean that you never join the new company. Or the negotiations could take weeks.

We have questions on this site about written offers that never arrived, and about companies that ghosted after giving a verbal offer.

The written offer could include conditions that will require you to pass a drug test, or background check, or even a physical. These take time.

Only after all the written offer is signed, all the conditions are met, and the starting date determined, do you think about when to tell your current company.

But assuming that everything goes quickly and your boss in still on leave, approach their temporary replacement, they will know the best way to inform the boss.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the manager's temporary replacement. There will be someone who is doing those parts of the manager's job that cannot be delays. It may be the manager's manager. It may be a subordinate. Whoever that is, their responsibilities include receiving and processing the resignation letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is company and manager specific.

The general rule is that you shouldn't inform your manager about planned job switches if they are likely (in your opinion) to terminate you immediately afterwards.

I have personally gave effectively several years notice, I have seen a question/answer in this site where a years notice resulted in working out the year and then a transfer to an office close to the new location (in another state). I have also personally seen two weeks notice turned into "don't bother coming in".

There's no universal laws or customs that you can count on, only company culture and your relationship with your manager.